# Trying to query all users from the user table in Parse.com

Tags: java, parse-platform

I am trying to print all users I have saved on Parse database on my screen. But somehow it doesn't work, I can print the data from all other tables expect the users... 
I think the problem is somewhere here, because when I change the "Todo" to User table it doesn't work anymore...

```
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Todo");
mainAdapter.setTextKey("title");
```

any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried "_users" (wild guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user class is special (so are a couple of others) because it's built into the platform. The name doesn't work because the name is private. As you can see `_Users` is the private name, but you shouldn't use it - you can't guarantee it won't change. The correct way to query is:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```